# How to refer to the curve_fit() (method, function?) of scipy.optimize

Tags: python, function, methods, scipy

The use of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` has been important in my current (astrophysics-related) research project.  Now that I'm working on a publication I want to make reference to `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` in my paper.  The current draft of my paper refers to `curve_fit()` as follows

> ...are fit using the curve_fit() function in the optimize module
>   of SciPy.

I want to make sure that my use of the words "function" and "module" are correct.  I am still learning the structure of modules, methods, and functions in Python and wanted to make sure that I am referring to them correctly.

Bonus:  The SciPy website's [citation guidelines](http://scipy.org/citing.html) state:

> For any specific algorithm, also consider citing the original author’s paper (this can often be found under the “References” section of the docstring).

As far as I can tell, `curve_fit()` has no references specified in its docstring, and neither does `leastsq()` which it relies on heavily.  I am planning on just citing the general SciPy library (as specified in the citation guidelines on the website) rather than the specific guideline.  Is there a more specific reference anyone can point me to?

Comment: Citing scipy - yea sure. But citing a least square implementation just because you used an algorithm that uses it is rather strange, isn't it? For me `using the curve_fit function of the scipy module` and the citation seems perfectly fine. The information that this function is in the `optimize` module seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

The notes in the SciPy reference to curve_fit() indicate it uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm through leastsq(). The notes under leastsq say it is a wrapper around MINPACK's lmdif and lmder algorithms. Under scipy.optimize.root() it mentions the Levenberg-Marquardt implementation in MINPACK, and points to: More, Jorge J., Burton S. Garbow, and Kenneth E. Hillstrom. 1980. User Guide for MINPACK-1. (R102 in the SciPy 0.13.0 Reference Guide Bibliography).